# ansi-c - assign array value in structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I need help assigning a value to an array with in a structure. Your help is greatly appreciated:

```
typedef struct _temp_t {
     int16_t _values[4];
} TEMP_T;

void func() {
    TEMP_T *temps;
    int x = 5;

    temps._values[0] = x;
}
```

I'm getting an error :

```
 ...src/rodm/ucdCom.c:512: error: request for member '_values' in something not a structure or union
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Aniket I've a feeling that will be proclaimed again without at least one allocation call in there somewhere.

Comment: Gotta dereference that pointer...

Comment: "Your help is greatly appreciated!" - just apparently never acknowledged. Dude, [LRN2 accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to your questions.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have the same feeling too. BTW -1 for this question because the OP does not accept answers

Comment: @Aniket And because he apparently haven't made the effort to learn about the topic he wants to be involved in... Things like this should be in any decent C tutorial.

Comment: @H2CO3 not to mention a harsh lesson in "being grateful"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TEMP_T *temps;
```

`temps` is a pointer, so it has no members, only `struct`s and `union`s have members.

After you allocated memory for `temps`, you could set

```
temps->_values[0] = x;
```

Or you can declare `temps` as a `TEMP_T`,

```
TEMP_T temps;
```

and leave the rest of the code as is.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> TEMP_T *temps;
> ```

Drop the `*` from that line. Then it will be a true `TEMP_T` object instead of a pointer.

Alternatively, `malloc` some memory to temps and then use:

```
temps->_values[0] = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP didn't have any sign of an allocated `struct TEMPT_T` anywhere.

He had a pointer, but nothing for it to point to. His code then attempts an assignment with member access syntax (`temps._values[0];`), as opposed to pointer access syntax (`temps->_values[0];`).

A slightly better version of his code might look like:

```
typedef struct _temp_t {
    int16_t _values[4];
} TEMP_T;

void func(struct TEMPT_T in) {
    TEMP_T *temps = &in;
    int x = 5;

    temps->_values[0] = x;
}
```

The function's new definition implies that a `struct TEMP_T` must exist for it to be used, and thus the pointer access into the structure becomes legal.